# How to have Java classes generated from WSDL implement an interface

Tags: java, wsdl, jaxb, cxf, xjc

Our main wsdl has a series of wsdl imports. Each sub-wsdl imports common.xsd and defines the request and reply objects for a particular operation.

I want the request objects in each of the sub-wsdl documents to implement a common interface.

First, I tried using xsd:extension and extracted the common elements to a base class. This works, but changes the publicly exposed wsdl and I don't want to do that. It has been stable and unchanged for a while now. This change should be completely transparent to consumers of the web services.

I found this:
http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin

So I should be able to use
        <inheritance:implements>com.acme.foo.MyInterface </inheritance:implements>

But this requires requires running jaxb w/ "-Xinheritance" and I can't seem to figure out how to do that in my maven build. I'm using org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:wsdl2java to generate Java source from wsdl.

Do I need to extract the schema(s) from the wsdl to xsds and generate the Java sources directly with JAXB?

Are there any other options?

Thanks.

Comment: I find `cxf-codegen-plugin` very useful for generating a webservice from WSDL ... but for generating POJOs from schema, I prefer using `cxf-xjc-plugin` which can be configured to use the `Inheritance plugin` like so: https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/8163296

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Using+JAXB2+Basics+Plugins+with+CXF). You'll need to do something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlOptions>
            <wsdlOption>
                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/CustomerService.wsdl</wsdl>
                <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/binding.xml</bindingFile>
                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/binding.xjb</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
                <extraargs>
                    <extraarg>-xjc-Xinheritance</extraarg>
                </extraargs>
            </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version><!-- version --></version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Link is broken.